# how can get the page number at the first page of content chapter

Tags: titles, page-numbering, titletoc

\documentclass[12pt,notitlepage]{thesis}
\begin{document}

```
\tableofcontents

    \thispagestyle{plain}


    \cleardoublepage
    \pagebreak \pagebreak \pagebreak

\listoffigures
        \thispagestyle{plain}
         \pagebreak
            \cleardoublepage
\listoftables
        \thispagestyle{plain}
         \pagebreak

    \cleardoublepage

    \mainmatter
    \doublespacing
```

\end{document}

[image]

how can put page number for the first page of content also for the list of figures

Comment: It looks like you're using some form of template to produce this document in its current form. As such, it heavily depends on the template how you can adjust to have page numbers on the first page of the ToC (or even why it's not there). Can you provide the community with a minimal example that we can copy-and-paste-and-compile and see exactly what you're seeing? See [I've just been asked to write a minimal working example (MWE), what is that?](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764) Can you do that?

Comment: please see the editing

Comment: `thesis` is a non-default document class. Where can we find `thesis.cls`?